# Print text between two XML tags

Tags: sed, xml

Consider the following excerpt from a large XML file:

```
  ...
  <serverName someKey="false" anotherKey="0.05" thirdKey="0.04">
    <default>blah.blah.blah</default>
    <region name="US">us.blah.net</region>
    <region name="EU">eu.blah.net</region>
    <region name="IL">il.blah.net</region>
  </serverName>
  ...
```

How do I print the the lines between the opening tag `<serverName ...>` and the closing tag `</serverName>`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`sed` is a great tool but XML will eventually make any programmer who approaches it with a REGEX cry. I know. I've been there. If there is even the smallest chance that your data will change, you want a proper XML parser.

My choice would be to use BeautifulSoup but it makes handling it directly from Bash fairly hard. If you want to write an intermediary Python script, that's still an option... Otherwise `xpath` is a fairly classic option. It's a wrapper around Perl's libxml library and it does some fairly powerful things.

```
sudo apt-get install libxml-xpath-perl
```

And for your example, here's how I'd do this in [the xpath query language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XPath):

```
xpath -e '*/serverName/*' big_xml_file.xml
```

Again, if you need to do anything useful with this XML, consider something even stronger like BeautifulSoup and Python.

Comment: gives me error `Cannot open file '-e' at /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl/XML/XPath.pm line 53`

Answer (score 4):

```
sed -n '/<serverName/,/<\/serverName/p' big_xml_file.xml
```

Did the trick (adapted from [this post](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/programming-9/%5Bgrep-awk-sed%5Dparsing-text-between-xml-tags-527480/) at linuxquestions.org).

On Ubuntu 14.04:

```
$ sed -n '/<serverName/,/<\/serverName/p' big.xml
<serverName someKey="false" anotherKey="0.05" thirdKey="0.04">
  <default>blah.blah.blah</default>
  <region name="US">us.blah.net</region>
  <region name="EU">eu.blah.net</region>
  <region name="IL">il.blah.net</region>
</serverName>
```

Comment: this dosn't work (bash, debian wheezy)

Comment: Works on ubuntu xenial. Can you explain, how?

Comment: I think I got it. It's a range. From line matching pattern, to line matching pattern after `,`.

Comment: Problem: the matching is greedy.

Comment: It solved my problem too and thank you. Can you pls explain the pattern .

Answer (score 0):

I can also imagine that you need to find a particular server from a longer list along with particular settings or regions based on some given conditional paths.

In that case, I would recommend wrapping your XPATH statements and conditions in an XSLT stylesheet. There are a number of XSLT parsers available in the repositories to work with the command line, PHP, Perl, Python, Java, etc.

[XSLT](http://www.w3schools.com/xsl/) is very powerful and can output text, xml, and html.