# How do I replace content of XML file by using shell scripting sed command?

Tags: scripts, sed

I have a `config.xml` file which shows:

```
<userid>myUserId</userid>
<password>myPass</password>
```

How can I replace `myUserId` and `myPass` by using `sed`?

Comment: replace myUserID and myPass with what?

Comment: with the argument I passed, let say I execute a shell script called "changeUser.sh"

./changeUser.sh myname mypass

Comment: Do you know the initial value of myUserId and myPass or do you want to place your own values between the tags without knowing what the previous entries were? If so then you're looking for an xml parser. [This Q&A](http://askubuntu.com/questions/284983/print-text-between-two-xml-tags) might be helpful.

Comment: What is the occurrence of those tags, do they appear only once on the entire file?

Comment: How do I apply sed -n '/<serverName/,/<\/serverName/p' big_xml_file.xml
 In my scenario??how to replace it without knowing what was it?

Comment: @Lucio, I need to delete the data between tag and insert a new one. But sometimes the tag is not in line..it is very trouble some to me.

Comment: I think you should instead use an xml parser.

Comment: @Braiam I have been researching for 2 days, still cannot find out the best solution maybe you are right

Answer (score 1):

```
sed "s/myUserId/$1/;s/myPass/$2/" originalfile
```

Comment: Could you explain?

Comment: if you run the script as: `./changeUser.sh ID PASS`, then positional arguments $0, $1, $2 are ./changeUser.sh, ID, PASS. Use ' ' for literals, and use " " for variables. s means substitute.

Comment: What if I don't know what was my userId and password in between tag?

Comment: probably you can use a regular expression, something like `"<password>.*</password>"` to match.

Comment: How can I do this for multiple xml files ?

Comment: This manipulates XML as a string.  This is inherently brittle and should be avoided.

Answer (score 1):

Solution Found

```
echo "cat //body/username" | xmllint --shell config.xml | sed '/^\/ >/d' | sed 's/<[^>]*.//g'
```

Can anyone explain this complex regex to me (^_^")

Comment: How does this change config.xml?

Answer (score -2):

```
sed 's/old/new/g' test.txt > test1.txt
```

Comment: This manipulates XML as a string.  This is inherently brittle and should be avoided.